# How to calculate quantiles in a pandas multiindex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas multiindex DataFrame, and I want to calculate the quantiles of its values over a specific index level. It's better to explain with an example.

First, let's create the DataFrame:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

item = ('A', 'B')
item_type = (0, 1, 2)
location = range(5)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(item, item_type, location)),names=('Item', 'Type', 'Location'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 3), index=idx,columns=('C1', 'C2', 'C3'))
df
```

Let's say we want to calculate a table of the median of the column values for each Item and Type over all locations. This is easy enough to do with the builtin .median method:

```
median_df = df.median(level=[0,1])
median_df
```

This will produce a three-column DataFrame with multiindex=(Item, Type). It works for most common functions like .mean, .max, .min, etc.

But it does not work for .quantile--strangely enough, quantile does not have the 'level' parameter.

How can I calculate a given quantile in the same way as I did for the median, etc?

Answer (score 7):

Apply the `quantile` function by first grouping by your multiindex levels:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).quantile()
```

The same result will work for the `median` function, so the following line is equivalent to your code `df.median(level=[0,1])`:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).median()
```

Against the `GroupBy` object returned by `groupby` function, you have also the `agg` function that allows you to bulk several function calls at once, and the resulting dataframe will have several levels for the columns:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(['median', 'quantile'])
```